# Java Servlet - Logger and configuration file

Tags: java, servlets, logging

Probably a simple issue. I have a logger that I am using in a Servlet:

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(x.class.getName());
```

And the property file (logging.properties):

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = output.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

So I can't get my output.log file to output (or find it mind you). So:

1. Where do I need to put my logging.property file in a normal Eclipse project Dynamic Web Program? I currently placed it in my WebContent\Web-INF folder.
2. Where does the file output?
3. Do I need to explicity read the property file? My understanding is that this file should be read by the Logger API depending on a property location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer your questions.

1. Put properties file in `classpath`, means put in `src` folder in your eclipse
2. you have to mention the path where it has to print the log.

   java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern= "path";

read this link to know http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

1. No you dont need to read explicitly in web application, framework will load from class path

P.S: i will recommend  `log4j`.

Comment: Moved the file to the src directory. Is FileHandler.file a legit property? Or is the FileHandler.pattern the property? I tried it regardless and had no luck still. Do I need to read that logging.property file within my code?

Comment: Went with log4j. That worked 100%. Not sure why the other way didn't work considering set up was identical...